# How to access a function in another class being within the same instance?

Tags: iphone, swift, function

I am currently creating a login project in Swift 3.
I have a main view controller which contains

1. a container, which includes a page viewcontroller and multiple pages
2. a custom "menu" at the bottom which includes two buttons for navigating the page view controller and a custom page control

[This is my storyboard setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZSNh.png)

The view the user will be presented with is made of the pages controlled by the page viewcontroller, at the top, and the control menu, at the bottom. When the user clicks on the buttons in the control menu this code will be executed in the main viewcontroller:

```
@IBAction func buttonNext(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("buttonNext has been pressed!")
    nextPageWithIndex(index: nextIndex)
}
```

and here is the function it calls:

```
func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int) {

        let nextWalkthroughVC = pages[index]
        pageContainer.setViewControllers([nextWalkthroughVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("nextPageWithIndex has been executed with Index \(index)!")

        if currentIndex as Int? == 2 {
            currentIndex = 2
        } else if currentIndex as Int? == 1 {
            currentIndex = 2
        } else if currentIndex as Int? == 0 {
            currentIndex = 1
        } else {
            currentIndex = 0
            print("currentIndex was in inpossible state!")
        }

        checkButtonNavigation()
        assignIndexes()

        if let index = currentIndex {
            pageControl.currentPage = index
            print("PageControl updated")
        }
}
```

`checkButtonNavigation()` checks if the buttons at the bottom should be displayed depending on the page which is currently being displayed.

---

I am trying to implement a button of one of the pages (in this case page1) which navigates the user to the next page.

I tried to execute the function `nextPageWithIndex(index: 1)` with `varAccountRegisterMainViewController.nextPageWithIndex(index: 1)` on the action of pressing the button in the page1 viewcontroller class by defining:

```
var varAccountRegisterMainViewController: accountRegisterMainViewController!
```

in the AppDelegate, 
and:

```
varAccountRegisterMainViewController = accountRegisterMainViewController()
```

in the page1 viewcontroller.

Sadly that doesn't seem to work. I get "fatal error: Index out of range" at the point:

```
let nextWalkthroughVC = pages[index]
```

in the function `nextPageWithIndex(index: 1)` in the main viewcontroller. I checked what count the array "pages" has. It's 0. When I execute the function right from the main viewcontroller, though, it has 3 as it should have. [Here is the error as an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTbfQ.jpg)

Thank you for your help!

---

**EDIT:**

here is how the pages Array is set-up:

At the beginning of the main viewcontroller class the following code is added:

```
var pages = [UIViewController]()
```

In the viewDidLoad() that code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDAccountRegisterPage1ViewController")
let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDAccountRegisterPage2ViewController")
let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDAccountRegisterPage3ViewController")
pages.append(page1)
pages.append(page2)
pages.append(page3)
```

---

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

I put the declaration of "pages" also into the externalNext() function. Now that problem is solved but there is another one... this is how the function looks now:

```
func externalNext(index: Int) {

    var pageContainer: UIPageViewController!

    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDAccountRegisterPage1ViewController")
    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDAccountRegisterPage2ViewController")
    let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDAccountRegisterPage3ViewController")
    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)
    pages.append(page3)

    // Create the page container
    pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    pageContainer.delegate = self
    pageContainer.dataSource = self
    pageContainer.setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    // Add it to the view
    view.addSubview(pageContainer.view)
    pageContainer.view.addSubview(pageControlView)

    print("Current array count of pages is \(pages.count)")
    print("Function: nextPageWithIndex has been called with index \(index)")
    let nextWalkthroughVC = pages[index]
    pageContainer.setViewControllers([nextWalkthroughVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("nextPageWithIndex has been executed with Index \(index)!")

    pageControl.currentPage = index
    print("PageControl updated")

    print("Hello")
}
```

I copied the code from the top of the main viewcontroller class and just pasted it into the function. I alway get the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", though.

Is there any way I can redefine the objects in the function? 
Or is there any elegant way? My way looks very messy...

Thanks to Phillip Mills I know that is has something to do with being another instance of the class main viewcontroller. How can I access the function in there but within the same instance? The main viewcontroller is visible all the time.

Thank you!

Comment: How does the `pages` array get set up in `accountRegisterMainViewController`?

Comment: I just updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this: `accountRegisterMainViewController()` you are creating a new object, a different instance of that class.  Since the new one is not being displayed, `viewDidLoad` is never called and your array is empty.

You need to arrange links between objects so that the one loaded from your storyboard is also the one that `nextPageWithIndex` is called on.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know it would create a new instance of that class. That also was a problem in other cases for me. How would you proceed in my situation? What do you mean with links?

Comment: I mean a variable in your page controller that points back to the main controller that came from the storyboard.  You should be able to do that in the app delegate by looking at what's loaded into the window's root view controller.

Comment: Could you provide me with some code, please? I am releatively new to programming. You would save my day!